# How to get the latest value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

How to get the latest value in every artistID?
I want to get the ww and ee (id=2,3)

```
    id  title   genreID  countryID  artistID  albumID  reg_count  down_count  createdAt           
------  ------  -------  ---------  --------  -------  ---------  ----------  ------------------- 
     1  qq            1          4         1        1         87          48  2020-05-05 01:00:00 
     2  ww            1          4         1        2         56          52  2020-05-05 03:00:00 
     3  ee            1          4         8       15         34          26  2020-05-05 21:00:00 
     4  rr            1          4         8       16         83          51  2020-05-05 05:00:00
```

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: 10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: See the grouwise-max tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MariaDB 10.2 or later you can use a `CTE` and window functions:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY artistId ORDER BY createdAt DESC) AS rn
  FROM contentnew 
  WHERE genreID = 1 AND mainContent = 1 AND countryID = 4
)
SELECT id, title, genreID, countryID, artistID, albumID, reg_count, down_count, createdAt
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

```
id  title   genreID     countryID   artistID    albumID     reg_count   down_count  createdAt
2   ww      1           4           1           2           56          52          2020-05-05 03:00:00
3   ee      1           4           8           15          34          26          2020-05-05 21:00:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=eca4744f1de852c8ff797fbb7a435238)

Comment: Thank you Nick. Then I am the beginner of MySQL. So could you please tell me another way that I can use it in the older version?
For example `SELECT * FROM contentnew WHERE genreID = 1 AND mainContent = 1 AND countryID = 4;`

Comment: @SatelBill your version is newer than 10.2 so you should be able to use this query without any problems. If you want to add a `WHERE` clause, see my edit (although I note you don't have a `mainContent` column in your sample data)